# How to web scrape the NBA table in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, statistics

With this code, I am only able to get the Atlantic Division but not the other divisions. I can't figure out the HTML tag for the other divisions. Here is the link to the source code from the website I am web scraping: view-source:https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_per_game.html

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_per_game.html")
page = soup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

Atlantic = page.find('tr').find_parent().get_text()
Central = page.find('tr').find_parent().get_text()
#Central = page.find('tr').find_parent().get_text()
Southeast = page.find('tr').find_parent().get_text()
Northwest = page.find('tr').find_parent().get_text()
Pacific = page.find('tr').find_parent().get_text()
Southwest = page.find('tr').find_parent().get_text()


View_Atlantic = open('Atlantic_Division.txt','a')
View_Atlantic.write(Atlantic)
View_Atlantic.close()

View_Central = open('Central_Division.txt','a')
View_Central.write(Central)
View_Central.close()

View_Southeast = open('Southeast_Division.txt','a')
View_Southeast.write(Southeast)
View_Southeast.close()

View_Northwest = open('Northwest_Division.txt','a')
View_Northwest.write(Northwest)
View_Northwest.close()

View_Pacific = open('Pacific_Division.txt', 'a')
View_Pacific.write(Pacific)
View_Pacific.close()

View_Southwest = open('Southwest_Division.txt', 'a')
View_Southwest.write(Southwest)
View_Southwest.close()

driver.quit()


while True:
    main = input("Which NBA division would you like to view?\n" +
    '1. Atlantic Division\n2 Central Division\n3  Southeast Division\n4  Northwest Division\n5  Pacific Division\n6  Southwest Division \n7  Quit')

    if main == '1':
        View_Atlantic = open('Atlantic_Division.txt' , 'r')
        lines = View_Atlantic.read()
        print(lines)
        View_Atlantic.close()

    if main == '2':
        View_Central = open('Central_Division.txt', 'r')
        lines = View_Central.read()
        print(lines)
        View_Central.close()

    if main == '3':
        View_Southeast = open('Southeast_Division.txt', 'r')
        lines = View_Southeast.read()
        print(lines)
        View_Southeast.close()

    if main == '4':
        View_Northwest = open('Northwest-Division.txt', 'r')
        lines = View_Northwest.read()
        print(lines)
        View_Northwest.close()
    if main == '5':
        View_Pacific = open('Pacific_Division.txt', 'r')
        lines = View_Pacific.read()
        print(lines)
        View_Pacific.close()

    if main == '6':
        View_Southwest = open('Southwest_Division.txt','r')
        lines = View_Southwest.read()
        print(lines)
        View_Southwest.close()

    if main == '7':
        print('Bye!')
        break
```

I want to be able to display the NBA team and the team record by choosing a certain NBA division.

Comment: I can see teams links grouped by locality e.g. Pacific. Where are you expecting to get these different tables?

Comment: don't you get all of the teams in `Atlantic` variable?